# AWS Version 4 signature snippet code with example in javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I have AWS Rest API and need to generate AWS Version 4 Signature.
I searching and get many links.
Successfully generate signature but getting error like **"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."**.

Comment: Hi Milan, welcome to stackoverflow. We'll need a bit more information, have you written your own code to compute the signature or are you using a library? If you're using a library, which one?

Comment: I get idea from https://gist.github.com/davidkelley/c1274cffdc0d9d782d7e

Answer (score 1):

Generating an AWS v4 signature is complicated. If you're looking to learn about the process and implement it yourself, I recommend the AWS documentation. There's a [step-by-step walkthrough of the process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html), [examples (including one in Javascript)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-javascript) and [test suite](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-test-suite.html). It's a good exercise to do if you're learning!

Trying to follow someone else's example without the information AWS provide is going to be tough and I don't think you'll understand as much.

If you just want to sign stuff, I'd suggest using a library rather than writing your own. [AWS provide a library](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/) to use their services in the browser, and if you just want to sign requests, something like [aws4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4) is a lightweight way to do that.